# Linking a file for download in Node - Javascript, EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to have one of my EJS pages have a button to download a file from my Node.js webapp. I am using Node.js, Express, Passport, etc... Currently, when I click the link I have, it links to a page that says `Cannot GET /public/files/PRA.xlsx`

Here is the code that I have for the link:

```
<a href="/public/files/PRA.xlsx" download>Download PRA File</a>
```

And here you can see the file structure of my app.

[image]

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `<a href="/files/PRA.xlsx" download>Download PRA File</a>`

If you have the static middleware set up for express, it will mount the folder you specify as the location where files may be served from.

Example:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Will serve any files located in the `public` folder. If the public folder has a file like: image.png, you'll be able to get to it from `localhost:3000/image.png`.

If you want to serve that image from `localhost:3000/public/image.png`, you can do the following:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
```

There's more information on this in the express documentation.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thank you! I only had my middleware linked for my images folder, so it was not picking up the files folder.